# I need to convert this function from C# to VB.net - Convert INT to multi character string

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need to convert this function from C# to VB.NET for use in SSRS report.

This function should take a number/INT and return a multi character string.

```
So 26 would be simple Z
but 27 would = AA
78 = AAA 
79 = AAB
and so on
```

Function to convert:

```
public static String getColumnNameFromIndex(int column)
{
    column--;
    String col = Convert.ToString((char)('A' + (column % 26)));
    while (column >= 26)
    {
        column = (column / 26) -1;
        col = Convert.ToString((char)('A' + (column % 26))) + col;
    }
    return col;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for someone to use R# to decompile that code to VB.Net? You an do it yourself just fine... Do you have any particular problem reading code? Writing?

Comment: [C# To VB](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're being **LAZY** and i mean lazy you can use http://converter.telerik.com/

Here's the output for you:

```
Public Shared Function getColumnNameFromIndex(column As Integer) As String 
    column -= 1
    Dim col As String = Chr(Asc("A") + (column Mod 26))
    While column >= 26
        column = (column \ 26) - 1
        col = Chr(Asc("A") + (column Mod 26)) & col
    End While
    Return col
End Function
```

Comment: It does need some adjustments to produce properly compilable code: `Dim col As String = Chr(Asc("A") + (column Mod 26))` and `col = Chr(Asc("A") + (column Mod 26)) & col`.

Comment: I do not know vb.net at all, and I am helping someone out.  We tried that convert (I think that was the site) but as Andrew said it did not work correctly straight out of the conversion.

Comment: I made Andrew's adjustments.  I was just showing the lazy answer.  Next time i'll actually convert by hand.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to write that it needs `column = (column \ 26) - 1` (i.e. integer division) too.

Comment: with that last change it worked,   thank you.  I did try the auto convert website but it was not working and I am not familar enough with VB.NET to get it working correctly